# Get ProductCode from MSI File using DTF in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've created this function to grab the MSI ProductCode from the MSI file itself. i couldn't find any native method for it. So I've implemented it the following way:

```
public static string GetMSIProductCode(string msiFile)
{
    string _result = null;
    string productCodeQuery = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'";
    Session product = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, true);
    Database msiDB = product.Database;
    View msiView = msiDB.OpenView(productCodeQuery);
    msiView.Execute();
    Record _record = msiView.Fetch();
    _result = _record.GetString(2);
    msiView.Close();
    msiDB.Dispose();
    return _result;
}
```

Would you do it any different?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Almost all objects you work with here are disposable so wrapping them with the `using` would be a good start.
- The `msiDB` variable is not necessary.
- It is not necessary now to define the `result` above the query. Variables should be defined as close to their usage as possible.
- We use the `_` usually only for private fields not for local variables.
- You might consider the implicit type `var`. It would make your code less verbose.

After applaying this we get:

```
public static string GetMSIProductCode(string msiFile)
{
    var productCodeQuery = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'";
    using(var product = Installer.OpenPackage(msiFile, true))
    using(var msiView = product.Database.OpenView(productCodeQuery))
    {
        msiView.Execute();
        using (var record = msiView.Fetch())
        {
            return record.GetString(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: t3chb0t,
1. how do you know if an object is disposable?
2. how would you implement the following: Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent)

Comment: @DaveGitenburgh in a database or stream context there are usually a lot of disposable objects.  Later it's a gut feeling that something might be disposable. When you work with new types you can either see in the documentation if a class implements the `IDisposable` interface or just check if it has the `.Dispose()` method - like I did here because I couldn't find any docs about it :-|

Comment: @DaveGitenburgh 2. unfortunatelly I don't know an answer to this question.